# Alinhando imagem dinamicamente

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo uma área do site onde eu busco alinhar dinamicamente as imagens que virá dos possíveis "clientes", o problema que está acontecendo é que não sei quebrar a linha porque preciso que fique 3 imagens um do lado da outra, e após esta terceira imagem a quarta virá em baixo da primeira. Segue meu código.

Index:

```
<div id="middle">
                <div class="row-fluid" id="conteudo">
                    <ul>
                      <li class="min"><div id="miniaturas">
                          <div id="minCli">
                              <img height="157px" src="../imagens/mais.png" id="mais" href=""/>
                              <img height="157px" src="../imagens/ronaldo.jpeg" id="imgFundo" href=""/>
                          </div>
                          </div></li>

                                          <li class="min"><div id="miniaturas">
                          <div id="minCli">
                              <img height="157px" src="../imagens/mais.png" id="mais" href=""/>
                              <img height="157px" src="../imagens/ronaldo.jpeg" id="imgFundo" href=""/>
                          </div>
                        </div></li>

                                          <li class="min"><div id="miniaturas">
                          <div id="minCli">
                              <img height="157px" src="../imagens/mais.png" id="mais" href=""/>
                              <img height="157px" src="../imagens/ronaldo.jpeg" id="imgFundo" href=""/>
                          </div>
                                              </div></li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
#minCli { width: 229px; height: 171px; background-color: white; }
#miniaturas {   margin-left: 15vw; margin-top: 5vh; }
#mais {   margin-left: -27px; z-index: 2; width: 50px; height: 50px; margin-top: 6vh; position: absolute; }
img#imgFundo {   margin-left: -115px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 229px;
  height: 171px;
  opacity: 0.75;
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  filter: alpha(opacity=75);
  -webkit-filter: opacity(0.75);
  filter: gray;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  image-rendering: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
img#imgFundo:hover { 
 opacity:1;
 -moz-opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 -webkit-filter: opacity(1);
 filter: none; /* Firefox 10+ */
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
 image-rendering: auto;
}
.min { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Crie um [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: como faço isso ?

Comment: Clique no link que ele postou e coloque o código lá, salve, e depois compartilhe a URL do fiddle criado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `display: inline-block;` deveria fazer exatamente o que está pedindo:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150/"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Portanto, isto pode ser um indicativo de algum estilo impedindo que o layout funcione corretamente. Tente, por exemplo, retirar o `position: absolute;` (ou, adicionar `position: relative;` no `.min)`.

Outra coisa que pode estar gerando problema é o uso do mesmo `id` em elementos distintos. Utilize um `id` único para cada elemento, ou troque `minCli` e `miniaturas` para serem classes. Nesse caso, lembre de substituir o seletor em seu CSS (de `#id` para `.classe`).

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações porem o problema mudou, agora não estou conseguindo fazer com que o footer fique sempre em baixo, se eu coloco `fixed´ ele não desce apenas o conteúdo desce. que faço @falsarella

Comment: Tenta colocar `bottom: 0px;` no footer.